# ¿Puedo escribir las palabras con un acento macron?

Tags: acentuación

Quiero escribir palabras con un acento macron. No **sē** si puedo(como lo hice) hacerlo correctamente.

Por ejemplo:

> ¿Cōmo estās?

Yo se que las palabras se escriben con los acentos agudos y tildes.

Comment: Si, yo pense esto en el pasado. (Lo siento sobre el tilde en pense con la "e")

Answer (score 2):

En español, el macrón (`¯`) no existe; el único símbolo usado para acentuar es el acento agudo, llamado **tilde** (`´`).

Existen 3 tipos de acentos en español:

El acento ortográfico (se tilda):

- Acento de palabras agudas.
- Acento de palabras graves.
- Acento de palabras esdrújulas.

El acento prosódico (no se tilda):

- Acento léxico
- Acento oracional

El acento diacrítico (se tilda):

- Se usa para diferenciar palabras que se escriben igual pero tienen diferente significado.

Comment: Yo se (necesito un acento aguto en la e en se)

Comment: si quieres escribir el acento en la "e" el codigo es alt + 130 : é